# How resize putty window?

Tags: ssh, putty

There are a lot of questions and answers about resizing console windows which are opened by putty when user press `Open` button. But how to resize initial `puTTY Configuration` window opened before terminal starts?

[image]

Comment: You can't (other than by changing fonts/sizes which may not work correctly). It's a dialog box that is not designed to be resizable on the fly. Having said that putty is open source. You can change the source code yourself ...

Answer (score 2):

This dialog window is not resizable. The only (reliable) way is to ask a Putty developer about it.